# ASP.NET MVC controller return JSON on error. Not consistent on dev machine vs. dev server

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC controller returning Task in a FileUpload function.
(I use a Controller in stead of ApiController to make the file upload work properly)

My problem is whenever an exception is thown (for instance a file not being on a white list of allowed file types), my code behaves differently when debugging compared to code on a dev server I have.

My code:

```
//Exception is thown, message is put into the errorMessage parameter
Response.StatusCode = 500;
Response.StatusDescription = errorMessage;
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
return Json(new { Type = "Error", Message = errorMessage });
```

On the dev server, I get HTML result
[image]

I can't find any significant differences in web.configs
Does anyone know where to investigate ?
This might be a simple configuration thing, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Looks like you've got IIS custom errors configured on one server but not the other. Try setting [the `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors?view=netframework-4.8) to `true`.

Comment: Is that the same as <customErrors mode="Off" /> in web.config ?

Comment: @thomas At first check the connection string,  after this check window app log of the server. All details about the error there.

Comment: Ok, thank's. I just tried, and got the same result :-(   I'm now wondering if the response is some how re-directed to somewhere ?!?

Comment: @thomas The `<customErrors>` element in `<system.web>` only applies to ASP.NET custom errors. IIS has its own set of custom errors in the `<httpErrors>` element under `<system.webServer>`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming. Actually, setting <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors> worked.

Make this into an answer, and I will mark it. Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS custom errors are intercepting the response and replacing it with an error page. Either setting `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` or changing the `httpErrors[existingResponse]` setting to `PassThrough` should allow the original response to be returned.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```